# Where is the wordplay of "A chicken crossing the road is poultry in motion"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I saw this sentence as an example of pun or wordplay. But I couldn't find out where the wordplay is. Any idea?

Comment: Why people downvote without bringing some reasons? I'm so mad about this behavior. Isn't it a little non-civil and rude?

Comment: My guess is that they have downvoted because they don't think that the 'explain this joke' sort of requests are interesting or likely to be useful to other users.

Comment: @Saeed Neamati: My apologies. I *did* downvote for the reason given by z7sg. I normally do say why I'm downvoting - for some reason I mistakenly assumed you did in fact recognise the wordplay, and simply wanted an excuse to post a 'joke'.

Comment: @Saeed: do note that if you hover over the downvote button, the alt text says "this question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". That's not one, but three potential (and valid) reasons for downvoting.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Graceful movement is often described as "poetry in motion"; the pun is in the similarity in sound between *poetry* and *poultry*. If one isn't familiar with the common phrase, then the humour disappears.

Comment: Yeah @Stan, you're right. I wasn't familiar with "poetry in motion". Thanks.

Comment: +1. Not having a decent grasp of the idioms of any language is likely to make much of the humor in that language a lot less funny.

Comment: I knew a popular jazz song called "poultry in motion"...
which further confused the meaning of this, as that was the only phrase with which I was familiar